# Getting #N/A in excel using IF and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I have a database & order request in excel. I want to set the format across all the database quantity column, so that when quantity is entered in the order request, using vlookup, it finds the code in the request form and matches it with the database and adjusts the database quantity. It works fine it there is a code already in the request form. But if the request form is blank, it throws back #VALUE! its doing my head in for hours
heres what i have:

=36-(IF('Order Request'!B4:B11="","",VLOOKUP('Stock Database'!B11,'Order Request'!$B$4:$G$11,5,FALSE)))

The 36 is quantity already in the db. The IF statement is incase the quantity section is blank in the request form that it wont throw back a #N/A. When the data is already in the reqest form, this works perfectly
=57-VLOOKUP('Stock Database'!B10,'Order Request'!$B$4:$G$11,5,FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use =IFERROR and get 0 in case of error. The final formula: 
=57-IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Stock Database'!B10,'Order Request'!$B$4:$G$11,5,FALSE),0)